# If Statement combined with InputBox

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word, inputbox

here is what I am trying to do:

The file is supposed to save itself according to the user's input and even if there is an input at all. Meaning, if a user has not made any inputs yet, the IF-Statement should return the first part (thats why UserName = ""). But if a user had previously already entered something, I want it to return the second part of the IF-Statement.

The original name of the file is 20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_00_ and if Jack is the first person to open that document and create a protocol, the name is supposed to be: 20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_00_Jack and only asking for Jack's Name. If Jack wants Steve to go over this document, then word should realize, Jack already saved this document (entered his initials or his name) and it will ask Steve which version this document is currently being on and add Steve behind Jack. Meaning:
20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_01_JackSteve while Steve only entered his name and 1.

I am a newbie & your help is much appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim MyDate As String
Dim UserName As String

If UserName = "" Then

    FilePath = "//SRVDC\Arbeitsordner\Intern\Meetings\Entwürfe\"
    MyDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
    Filename1 = "_Besprechungsnotizen_i_00_"
    UserName = InputBox("Wer erstellt? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FilePath & MyDate & Filename1 & UserName

Else

    FilePath = "//SRVDC\Arbeitsordner\Intern\Meetings\Entwürfe\"
    MyDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
    Filename1 = "_Besprechungsnotizen_i_0"
    Filename2 = "_"
    UserName = InputBox("Wer bearbeitet? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
    Version = InputBox("Welche Version? (in ganzen Zahlen)")

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FilePath & MyDate & Filename1 & Version & Filename2 & UserName
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Although your question explains the goal of your project it isn't clear what help you need. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69130132/edit) and explain clearly what it is that you need help with. It may be helpful to review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The logic is not clear. You should ask for the UserName = InputBox before the If statement. Or use maybe the If ActiveDocument.Saved https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.save.

Comment: You need some place to store the user name if it has already been entered before. Your code does not seem to have any thing like that plus the variable named as "UserName" doesn't have any value assignment. So the logic will always  be true.the else block will never be executed.  Are you trying to do it in excel?

Comment: I edited to original post and hope its easier to understand what my goal is. And now I am trying to do it in word

Comment: @mishu36 can you elaborate? Cause this is exactly what seems to happen. Doesnt matter if somebody entered already or not, the logic is always true. please try to explain like you know youre explaining to a newbie

Comment: See one method with a Content Control at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/save-document-based-on-template-in-special-folder/e1a71dbc-4af8-4216-9112-449d013115fd?tm=1596934485817

Comment: @Jens1411 Look at your code. After declaring the variable at **Dim UserName As String**. You have directly used **If UserName = "" Then**. You haven't assigned any valu to UserName variable. This is why **If UserName = "" Then** will always be true. And **Else** block will never be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Const FilePath As String = "//SRVDC\Arbeitsordner\Intern\Meetings\Entwürfe\"
    Const OrigFileName As String = "20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_00_"
    Dim Filename As String: Filename = "_Besprechungsnotizen_i_0"
    Dim MyDate As String: MyDate = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim Version As String

    If Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) = OrigFileName Then
        'file has not been resaved
    Else
        'file has been saved before so extract data from filename
        Dim nameElements As Variant
        nameElements = Split(Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0), "_")
        UserName = nameElements(UBound(nameElements))
        Version = nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 1)
    End If
    If UserName = "" Then
        UserName = InputBox("Wer erstellt? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
        Version = "0_"
    Else
        Dim currentUser As String
        currentUser = InputBox("Wer bearbeitet? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
        If currentUser = UserName Then
            'you need to figure out what you want to do in this case
        Else
            'you also need to figure out what you want to do when you already have two names
            UserName = UserName & currentUser
        End If
        'do you really need to prompt the user for the version number?
        'couldn't you just increment the existing number, e.g.
        'Version = Format$(Version + 1, "00")
        Version = InputBox("Welche Version? (in ganzen Zahlen)") & "_"
    End If
    
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FilePath & MyDate & Filename & Version & UserName

End Sub
```

Comment: you got my idea and its pretty damn close to what I am trying to do. its not quite working the way though. apparently, it goes straight to the line: Else
        UserName = InputBox("Wer bearbeitet? (Name in Firmenkurzform)") And when I change names again, it wont add the new name, it will just replace.

Comment: meaing it skips:  If UserName = "" Then
        UserName = InputBox("Wer erstellt? (Name in Firmenkurzform)")
        Version = "0_". my original file is named 20210910_Besprechungsnotizen_00_. its just when the first person saves it, it should stay 00_(+name). and every other time, it should ask for the version and add the new name

Comment: @Jens1411 - When you ask a question here you need to provide *all* the information needed to provide an answer, e.g. the original file name. Keep in mind that we cannot see your document, or read your mind.

Comment: I've edited my original post one more time. Hope this is a much better explanation and I appreciate your help.

Comment: I am getting an error: If LBound(Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")) = OrigFileName Then

Comment: the idea is to have the original file in //SRVDC\Arbeitsordner\Intern\Meetings\ (1 folder before) but even after pasting inside the Entwürfe folder (meaning in the same) it still gives me the same error code

Comment: to answer your questions: a third person will be added again, just as I hoped for. I need the program to ask for version numbers, because there will be times where you save and want to increment a new number and there may be times where the user makes 1 or 2 minor grammatical changes and doesnt want to increment the number and when the user does not want to increment the number and does not want to add his name, he could just press ctrl + s.

Comment: you made a really good point. I actually updated my original post again asking for automatic increments and some other few changes.

Comment: @Jens1411 - SO exists to provide specific answers to specific questions. It is not a code writing service. Questions should only be edited to make the original question clearer or provide additional information necessary for an answer to be given. FWIW the code posted already includes a means of incrementing the version number. The other comments in the code are not questions, they are things that you need to consider/problems that you need to solve.

Comment: Are you referring to this line? If Version = vbYes Then
            newVersion = Format$(Version + 1, "0"). Somehow it doesnt work and I cant figure out why it wouldnt work. Your solution did exactly as I asked. But then I ran a few examples with co-workers and realized that it needs some adjustments. I've already changed the code from yours as you can tell if you compared both. If I cant solve it, I'll post a new post since its technically a new code. Thanks anyway, you helped a lot!

Comment: can you explain the first few lines? I mean you did exactly what I am trying to do with splitting the ActiveDocument.name, but I cant figure out what that means. If you could explain how you did that, I might be able to finish the rest since I've successfully implemented the version numbers thanks to your help. using this code means I cant really post to the other thread regarding this and you did solve my original post. Since I dont wanna create a third thread, it would be cool if you could just explain those lines that give me most trouble understanding

Comment: @Jens1411 - the [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function is used to separate the file name into an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#array) of elements with the underscore as delimiter. The last element in the array is assumed to be the user name, which is preceded by the version. If you add a second user name separated by an underscore both these elements will contain user names, and you will have no way of getting the current version number.

Comment: I understand that with the delimiter. but I really dont get this part ".")(0) like the second part of the function. I assume the "." means the function until the dot? but why the 0?and when you use it with -1. why did you do it in the one part fo the function but not in the other? doesnt -1 mean you want to return all arrays? but you only return 1 array. I understand split, I understand why ActiveDocument.name and I understand the delimiter. So I dont understand the middle part of the first function with "."(0) and I dont understand the return functions ubound espeicallly with the -1 behind it

Comment: and I dont get why you even do a double split to begin with

Comment: @Jens1411 - evidently you don't understand arrays. `Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0)` returns an array containing the file name in the first element, which has an index of zero, and the file extension in the second element. `nameElements(UBound(nameElements))` returns the value of the last element of the arrary, `nameElements(UBound(nameElements) - 1)` returns the value of the element before the last.

Comment: got it. why did you do split(split though?

Comment: @Jens1411 - that should be obvious, to remove the file extension.

Comment: aaah got it. ok I did finish my code as of right now thanks to those explanations. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Working with `InputBox()` can be a bit slow and tricky. Anyway, try printing whatever you have entered and see where in the code you are.

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim userName As String
    Dim usedVersion As String
    
    userName = InputBox("Enter username")
    If userName = "" Then
        Debug.Print "UserName is empty"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Username " & userName & " was entered."
        Debug.Print "Asking for version now:"
        usedVersion = InputBox("Welche Version? (in ganzen Zahlen)")
        Debug.Print "Version "; usedVersion; " was entered"
    End If

End Sub
```

This is how the debug looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesnt solve what I am trying to do. Perhaps I should elaborate on what I am actually trying to do: my goal is that the file is going to be saved by date_Besprechungsnotizen_Version_Name. But the Version should be automatically 0 when the first person enters his name and after that, word should realize at least a second person is putting something into the inputBox, so word will ask about which version and who is editing. Hope this makes more sense

Comment: I edited the original post to better explain my goals